# How to insert checkbox values into table using PHP?

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, pdo, sql-insert

Anyway, I have a form for registering volunteers - normal stuff, it all passes. But then I have a checkbox problem. Volunteers can help at different festivals and can be available for tasks (2 tables, where the id of the volunteer corresponds to id of festival/task).
The code now is incomplete because I kept just getting errors, latest being:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Vardump results:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "8" [1]=> string(2) "10" } array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" [3]=> string(1) "4"
```

Can anyone help me to get me on the right track so I can move on?

Update/edit: weird typo at statements2 and 3 and another typo - but no solution to the problem though. Changing the `bindparam(':t_id',$task, PDO::PARAM_INT)` to `bindparam(':t_id',$task, PDO::PARAM_STR)` doesn't work either (although I know the problem is probably somewhere in that statement).

addvolunt.php

```
     <?php
    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
    }
    include_once 'dbConnect.php';

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome - <?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/menu.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <table class="center"><tr><td>
                    <p class="P1">Voeg hier een vrijwilliger toe</br>
                    <hr></hr>
                </p>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['reg_btn'])) {
    $p_fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $p_lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $p_dob = $_POST['dob'];
    $p_adres = $_POST['adres'];
    $p_pc = $_POST['pc'];
    $p_loc = $_POST['loc'];
    $p_coun = $_POST['coun'];
    $p_phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $p_phone2 = $_POST['phone2'];
    $p_mail = $_POST['mail'];

  if($volunt->createVolunt($p_fname,$p_lname,$p_dob,$p_adres,$p_pc,$p_loc,$p_coun,$p_phone,$p_phone2,$p_mail)) {;
        echo("Vrijwilliger toegevoegd");

    }

    else{
        echo("Registration Failed");
        var_dump($_POST['tid']);
        var_dump($_POST['fest']);
    }

}
?>
<div id="formdiv">    
<form method="post" id="form">
            <table class="center" width="30%" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>Voornaam</td><td><input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Voornaam" required /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Achternaam</td><td><input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Achternaam" required /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Geboortedatum dd/mm/jjjj</td><td><input type="text" name="dob" placeholder="Geboortedatum dd/mm/jjjj" required /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Adres</td><td><input type="text" name="adres" placeholder="Adres" required /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Postcode</td><td><input type="text" name="pc" placeholder="Postcode 1234AB" required /></td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Plaats </td><td><input type="text" name="loc" placeholder="Plaats" required /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Land </td><td><input type="text" name="coun" placeholder="Land" required /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Mobiel</td><td><input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Mobiel#" required /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Telefoon 2 </td><td><input type="text" name="phone2" placeholder="Vast#" required /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email </td><td><input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="Email" required /></td>
                </tr>

                <table class="center"><th colspan="2">Festivals</th>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="fest[]" value="1">Vurige Tongen</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="fest[]" value="2">Solstice</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="fest[]" value="3">Landjuweel</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="fest[]" value="4">Zaterdagen</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

                <table class="center"><th colspan="3">Taken</th>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="tid[]" value="1">Bar</td>
             <td><input type="checkbox" name="tid[]" value="2">Camping</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="tid[]" value="3">Hygiene</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="tid[]" value="4">Kassa</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="tid[]" value="5">Keuken</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="tid[]" value="6">Munt</td>
        </tr>
                    <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="tid[]" value="7">Parkeerbeheer</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="tid[]" value="8">Vrijwilligerscoordinatie</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="tid[]" value="9">Kantoor</td>
        </tr>
                    <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="tid[]" value="10">Runner</td>            
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="tid[]" value="11">Op/Afbouw</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="tid[]" value="12">Techniek</td> 
        </tr>
    </table>

                <tr>
                    <td><button type="submit" name="reg_btn">Aanvallen</button></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </form>
</div>
</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

crud.php *part*

```
public function createVolunt($p_fname,$p_lname,$p_dob,$p_adres,$p_pc,$p_loc,$p_coun,$p_phone,$p_phone2,$p_mail){

    try{

        $statement = $this->Db->prepare("INSERT INTO RO_volunt(p_fname,p_lname,p_dob,p_adres,p_pc,p_loc,p_coun,p_phone,p_phone2,p_mail) VALUES (:p_fname,:p_lname,:p_dob,:p_adres,:p_pc,:p_loc,:p_coun,:p_phone,:p_phone2,:p_mail)") ; 
        $statement->bindparam(':p_fname',$p_fname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindparam(':p_lname',$p_lname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindparam(':p_dob',$p_dob,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindparam(':p_adres',$p_adres,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindparam(':p_pc',$p_pc,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindparam(':p_loc',$p_loc,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindparam(':p_coun',$p_coun,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindparam(':p_phone',$p_phone,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindparam(':p_phone2',$p_phone2,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindparam(':p_mail',$p_mail,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();
        $last_id = $this->Db->lastInsertId();

        $statement2 = $this->Db->prepare("INSERT INTO RO_eventsvol(id,e_id) VALUES (:id,:e_id)"); 
        $statement2->bindparam(':e_id',$fest, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement2->bindparam(':id',$last_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        foreach ($_POST['fest'] as $fest) {$statement2->execute(); }

        $statement3 = $this->Db->prepare("INSERT INTO RO_tasksvol(id,t_id) VALUES (:id,:t_id)"); 
        $statement3->bindparam(':t_id',$task, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement3->bindparam(':id',$last_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        foreach ($_POST['tid'] as $task) {$statement3->execute(); }


    } catch (PDOException $ex){
        echo $ex->getMessage();
        return false;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Hi Vivianne, pleased you solved it! We prefer self-answers here, rather than a SOLVED addendum. I've moved it to an answer below. You are very welcome to do that in the future, and you may even get rep points for it.

Comment: Ah thank you for the explanation and for changing it to the right format!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You require to bind parameter for each loop

```
 $statement2 = $this->Db->prepare("INSERT INTO RO_eventsvol(id,e_id)` VALUES (:id,:e_id)"); 
   foreach ($_POST['fest'] as $fest) {           
            $statement2->bindparam(':e_id',$fest, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $statement2->bindparam(':id',$last_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $statement2->execute(); } 


 $statement3 = $this->Db->prepare("INSERT INTO RO_tasksvol(id,t_id) VALUES (:id,:t_id)"); 
 foreach ($_POST['tid'] as $task) {            
        $statement3->bindparam(':t_id',$task, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement3->bindparam(':id',$last_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement3->execute();
        }
```

Comment: Solved it! Thanks!! (only thing is the typo ` after VALUES in the code you gave ;)) - but it works! 
Many many thanks all!!

Comment: @VivianneDaniels: ideally, if you can upvote answers you like, and accept one that gave you the most help, that is great. You don't _have_ to do this, but it is recommended - it is how we express appreciation here.

Comment: Yeah already clicked the upvote button, but it's not registering yet.. 
And indeed I really appreciated the quick responses!

Answer (score 0):

You've mis-typed your bound parameter names on queries 2 & 3

```
$statement2 = $this->Db->prepare("INSERT INTO RO_eventsvol(id,e_id) VALUES (:id,:e_id1)"); 
$statement2->bindparam(':e_id1',$fest, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement2->bindparam(':id',$last_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
foreach ($_POST['fest'] as $fest) {$statement2->execute();

$statement3 = $this->Db->prepare("INSERT INTO RO_tasksvol(id,t_id) VALUES (:id,:t_id1)"); 
$statement3->bindparam(':t_id1',$task, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement2->bindparam(':id',$last_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
foreach ($_POST['tid'] as $task) {$statement3->execute();
```

Will fix it

Comment: wow - talking about mistakes you just miss because of all the staring :P 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Solved: here is the correct code for people who have the same problem:

```
 $statement2 = $this->Db->prepare("INSERT INTO RO_eventsvol(id,e_id) VALUES (:id,:e_id)"); 
   foreach ($_POST['fest'] as $fest) {           
            $statement2->bindparam(':e_id',$fest, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $statement2->bindparam(':id',$last_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $statement2->execute(); } 

            $statement3 = $this->Db->prepare("INSERT INTO RO_tasksvol(id,t_id) VALUES (:id,:t_id)"); 
 foreach ($_POST['tid'] as $task) {            
        $statement3->bindparam(':t_id',$task, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement3->bindparam(':id',$last_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement3->execute();
        }
```